# Does the use of styleSheets in a dynamic manner add a lot of computation

Tags: qt

I have about 40 buttons that are also indicators (On or Off) and once a second I refresh the color of these indicators depending on the state.  I do this by changing the stylesheet. Is it over kill to do this and if so should I only set a new stylesheet when it the indicator has changed state or should I use something like QBrush?

Comment: Wouldn't it answer your question if you used the O/S performance monitor (`perfmon.exe` on Windows) to measure the amount of CPU computation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I found that with Qt 4.6.2 on Linux, setting a stylesheet to change the colour of the text on a QLabel is very slow.

The dynamic stylesheet looked like a great solution but for me, the necessary `setStyle()` was just as expensive as `setStyleSheet()`!

After much experimentation, I found this alternative to be at least twice as quick, and usually more than 50 times as quick:

```
QPalette palette = lbl->palette();
palette.setColor(QPalette::WindowText, Qt::gray);
lbl->setPalette(palette);
```

Depending on how your (static) stylesheet is set up, you'd have to replace `QPalette::WindowText` with `QPalette::Window` or `QPalette::Button`. See the [QPalette documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum) for details.

Comment: it's a cool concept. Unfortunate that they explicitly mention it is for "demo purposes only" and should "not be used for production" (although I did use it :)

Comment: @yanbellavance, do you have a link where they mention it is 'for demo purposes only' and 'should not be used in production?

Answer (score 12):

Do not dynamically set complete stylesheets. Instead, define an application wide stylesheet using dynamic stylesheet that you parse once at application startup. Then, in the stylesheet, define dynamic stylesheet properties as detailed in the [documentation](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-using-dynamic-properties):

> There are many situations where we need to present a form that has mandatory fields. To indicate to the user that the field is mandatory, one effective (albeit esthetically dubious) solution is to use yellow as the background color for those fields. It turns out this is very easy to implement using Qt Style Sheets. First, we would use the following application-wide style sheet:
>
> ```
> *[mandatoryField="true"] { background-color: yellow }
> ```

In your case, you could probably do something like this:

```
QPushButton[state="on"] {
  background-color: green;
}

QPushButton[state="off"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Then update the button 'state' property:

```
pushButton->setProperty("state", "on");
pushButton->setStyle(QApplication::style());
```

Unfortunately, for Qt 4.6 you will need to force a recomputation of the stylesheet by resetting the style of the widget, hence the `setStyle()` call.

Using dynamic stylesheets in this way is very fast. I am working on an application that makes heavy use of dynamic stylesheet properties and have not noticed any performance degredation.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  So from Qt 4.6 I will have to call pushButton->setStyle(QApplication::style()); everytime I change  the properties to affect the style?  I will put it in my code right now to avoid future problems.

Comment: are you absolutely sure that this will be the case in Qt 4.6?

Comment: I have not managed to get the dynamic behaviour to work without resetting the style. Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595476/are-qts-stylesheets-really-handling-dynamic-properties/1849127#1849127

Did you manage to get the dynamic behaviour without resetting the widget style? I am using Qt under Linux, not sure whether that makes any difference.

Comment: Just an optimalization on how to update without resetting the style entirely (from http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html):  tstFrame->setProperty("error",true);

tstFrame->style()->unpolish(tstFrame);

tstFrame->style()->polish(tstFrame);

tstFrame->update();

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel: Nice method! I found setStyle(QApplication::style()) better than unpolish and polish (or ensurePolished) method. I have an application that requires colors of around 50 buttons to be set using a loop. With unpolish-polish functions, usually first button created problem as its color did not get updated; dont know why. But with your approach, it works fine! Thanks!

Comment: Given `setStyleSheet()` is so expensive, a dynamic stylesheet makes a lot of sense. Unfortunately, I concur that in my Qt 4.6.2 on Linux experience, a subsequent `setStyle()` is necessary. Further, I found `setStyle()` is just as expensive as `setStyleSheet()`! It does allow me to delay and then selectively apply, so it's an improvement, but I'd still love to see a far less expensive way to dynamically change a widget's colour.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience stylesheets consume too much resources, better to avoid them if you can.

Comment: refresh rate was once a second and the quad core pc my app is running on was so smooth it was running at 0% :)