# How to change the styleSheet properties at runtime?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer, qtstylesheets

I'm using Qt, 5.9, Windows.
I'm trying to change the styleSheet properties after my program started, so the user can customize the appearance of the program.

I have not created a styleSheet file. Instead, in Qt's Design mode, I go to the properties of the element I'm trying to change, click the "styleSheet" property, and add properties I want to change in the window displayed by Qt.
Check the image 1* for the example. The red box shows where I add the styleSheet property and the green box shows where I click to get to the popup window that lets me add a styleSheet property.

Image 2* shows how the .ui code is written when I add styleSheet properties this way. The red box here shows how the code is written automatically in the .ui file.

In the Edit menu of the menuBar, I placed a submenu called "Appearance", with a few pre-set options of colors of the program and an option to customize the program yourself.
In image 3*, you can see the menu.

[image: Images 1, 2 and 3, respectively.]

When the user clicks one of the color options, it should change the styleSheet properties of the program, so the colors match the color chosen. The problem happens here.
Image 4 shows the code for clicking in these color options:

[image: Color options commands]

In the red square, the errors I have been getting, and the respective lines that produced them.
In the yellow square, two of many trials I have made.
In the blue square, the most seemingly effective tries. The one in line 21 wasn't compiled when I took the screenshot, but it only complained after compilation (but it did complained!). It says "notr" is not defined in this scope. So I tried declaring it.
The one in line 22 is gave me an error when I tried "string notr", saying that the string was not defined in this scope. I included the <stdlib.h>, and changed it to "std::string notr", but it is still complaining. Like you can see in the red box, it says "expected primary-expression before 'notr'".

What does it mean? How do I fix this, so I can change the styleSheet properties of my elements?
I thought of using styleSheet files for the pre-set colors, but I would like to avoid, if possible, using more files than needed. Also, how would the user be able o set a custom styleSheet, if the options are pre-set?

Thanks for the attention and help.

P.S.: Just as a bonus question. I'm trying changing basic colors first, then start advancing.
Ultimately, I want to be able to reproduce something like Substance Look and Feel, its way of handling colors, making gradients, or giving the titleBar more than one color. Does anyone know what route to take? I believe styleSheets are too weak to reproduce those effects, so I would like to know how else could I change a program to look even more like Susbtance's skins.
Thanks again.

*Images 1, 2 and 3 appear in the same image file, because StackOverflow wouldn't let me post more than 2 images.

Comment: It looks like a duplicate of an older question that got a nice answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562716/changing-stylesheet-dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`setProperty()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty) according to the documentation:

> Sets the value of the object's name property to value.
>
> If the property is defined in the class using `Q_PROPERTY` then true is
>   returned on success and false otherwise. If the property is not
>   defined using `Q_PROPERTY`, and therefore not listed in the meta-object,
>   it is added as a dynamic property and false is returned.

That is, the property must be defined in the class with that macro, but stylesheet does not meet those requirements so you will not be able to access with that method.

To dynamically change that property you must use the [`setStyleSheet()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop). For example in your case:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionBlack_triggered()
{
    centralWidget()->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(78, 78, 78);");
}

void MainWindow::on_actionBlack_Piano_triggered()
{
   //another color
    centralWidget()->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(111, 111, 111);");
}

void MainWindow::on_actionPok_dex_Orange_triggered()
{
   //another color
    centralWidget()->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(123, 22, 111);");
}
```

*Note:*

- Try to avoid using `std::string`, you must use [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html).
- The instruction `some_function(type_variable name_variable = some_value);` is not a valid C/C++ syntax

When in the design xml:

```
<property name="styleSheet">
 <string notr="true"> background-color: rgb (78, 78, 78);
 font 10pt &quot;Arial&quot;;
 color: rgb(220, 220, 220);<string>
</property>
```

`notr="true"` means that when you want to use the Qt translation system, this string will not be taken into account: No Translations.

That xml is never used by the compiler directly, which converts those .ui files to .h with the name ui_yourdesign.h.

The `setStyleSheet()` function is part of QWidget, so any class that inherits from `QWidget` can use it, ie QMenubar, QLineEdit, QTextEdit.

For example the xml you display:

[image]

Show that theBar menu is being applied to the property, that instruction could be changed through C ++ with the following statement:

```
ui->menuBar->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb (78, 78, 78); font 10pt; color: rgb(220, 220, 220);")
```

Comment: Some things you said I knew, some didn't occur to me (specially `some_function(type_variable name_variable = some_value);`, don't know how I could pass on `std::string string = "string"`).
Anyways, what a complete answer!
Thank you!

Comment: You must convert to QString: `std::string s = "some_text";
QString qstring = QString::fromUtf8(s.c_str());
centralWidget()->setStyleSheet(qstring);`. I would recommend using the native data types for Qt.

Comment: The above is reduced to: `QString qstring = "some_text";
centralWidget()->setStyleSheet(qstring);`, if we use the native types of Qt.

Comment: All CSS is not compatible with Qt StyleSheet, ie CSS is not equal to QSS, for more information read the following: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html

Comment: Didn't work (by the way, that's one of the things I've tried). Is there any function I have to call to "update" the styleSheet, or to render it again (I've tried repaint(), render(), setVisible(false) and then setVisible(true))?

Comment: You could provide your complete code through github, drive, dropbox, etc. to be able to prove what error you have.

Comment: I'll post on Github.
Did a last test. Placed some Dialog boxes on each color option.
Only Black color is being called. This is the log output:
`QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_actionPok_dex_Orange_triggered(),
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_actionPok_dex_Red_triggered(),
Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x1fb5a388`
Orange and Red have no signal, whatever that means. The styleSheet of black is not being parsed, so it reverses back to "no style sheet".

Comment: I have shown that code based on your screenshots, if you change the QActions it probably will not work.

Comment: I publish it in github, when I correct your code I will do a pull request

Comment: Your qss have syntax errors, I created a pull requests with the corrections, review and comment.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a QSS stylesheet file named "default.qss"  that defines your theme:

```
QMenu::item{
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
}

QWidget[accessibleName="myVideoWidget"] {
    border: 2px solid #383638;
}
```

You can change the style at runtime as follows:

```
QFile file(":/qss/default.qss");

file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString styleSheet = QString::fromLatin1(file.readAll());

// Option 1: Set theme for the inner central widget
ui->centralWidget->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);

// Option 2: Set theme for the entire application
this->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use for example `myPushButton->setStyleSheet("* { color: blue }");` take a look [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) in your case it is `ui->menuBar->setStyleSheet("your style sheet properties");` or `ui->centralWidget->setStyleSheet("your style sheet properties");`

Comment: In `centralWidget()->setStyleSheet("your style sheet properties");` how do I write the "your style sheet properties"? I've tried (taking background-color as example) `"{background-color: rgb(250, 120, 15);}"` or `"background-color: rgb(250, 120, 15);"` or `"centralWidget()->setProperty("styleSheet", "background-color: rgb(250, 120, 15);");"`
None of these work.

Comment: You don't need curly brackets when calling the setStyleSheet function: E.g `textbox->setStyleSheet("color:white; width:100px; height:50px;");`