# Why QTextDocument background color changes only once?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am using TextEditor from the example provided with Qt (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols1-texteditor-example.html). Here is the complete code https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/examples/quickcontrols/controls/texteditor?h=5.15

I have created a custom method **`void DocumentHandler::setBackgroundColor(const QColor &color)`** to change the background color of the overall HTML document.

My problem is whenever I call a method to change the background color of `QTextDocument` using `setDefaultStyleSheet`, it is executed only once. ie, my document background changes only once. For the next calls, I can see the qDebug printing correctly, but the setDefaultStyleSheet doesn't work. However, everything works perfectly with normal text, only not with `m_doc->toHtml()`.

How do I fix this?

**If I change m_doc->setHtml("some random text"), it works as required**

```
...

QColor DocumentHandler::backgroundColor() const
{
    return m_backgroundColor;
}

void DocumentHandler::setBackgroundColor(const QColor &color)
{

    m_backgroundColor = color.name(); // QColor variable
    m_doc->setDefaultStyleSheet("body{background-color: '"+ color.name() +"'}"); // m_doc is QTextDocument *
    m_doc->setHtml(m_doc->toHtml());

    qDebug() << "BACKGROUND COLOR CHANGED" << color.name() ;
    emit backgroundColorChanged();
}
```

In the QML, I have called it like this

```
...
DocumentHandlerModel {
    id: document
    target: textArea
    cursorPosition: textArea.cursorPosition
    selectionStart: textArea.selectionStart
    selectionEnd: textArea.selectionEnd
    backgroundColor: colorDialog2.color
    onFontFamilyChanged: {
        var index = Qt.fontFamilies().indexOf(document.fontFamily)
        if (index === -1) {
            fontFamilyComboBox.currentIndex = 0
            fontFamilyComboBox.special = true
        } else {
            fontFamilyComboBox.currentIndex = index
            fontFamilyComboBox.special = false
        }
    }
    onError: {
        errorDialog.text = message
        errorDialog.visible = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26249813/5366641?

Comment: @scopchanov, that is for `QLabel`.I coudnot find any such method for `QTextDocument`. You are right I think. I need to somehow refresh it. But don't know the exact way

Comment: Indeed. The answer is for widgets. `QTextDocument` works differently. I now the cause already. Give me some time to find a solution and I will write you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause

The documentation of [`QTextDocument::setDefaultStyleSheet`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#defaultStyleSheet-prop) says:

> Note: Changing the default style sheet does not have any effect to the existing content of the document.

You try to overcome this by calling `setHtml` after `setDefaultStyleSheet` like that:

```
m_doc->setHtml(m_doc->toHtml());
```

However, this does not produce the desired result, because `setDefaultStyleSheet` actually embeds the background color **in** the `HTML` through the `bgcolor` `CSS` property.

To test this, add

```
m_doc->setHtml("<html><body><p>Test</p></body></html>");
qDebug() << m_doc->toHtml();
```

after

```
m_doc->setHtml(m_doc->toHtml());
```

The `HTML` content of `m_doc` from `<html><body><p>Test</p></body></html>`, when tested with `#FF00FF`, becames:

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\np, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n</style></head><body style=\" font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\" bgcolor=\"#ff00ff\">\n<p style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Test</p></body></html>"
```

**Note:** Please, notice that assignment: `bgcolor=\"#ff00ff\`.

So, by writing `m_doc->setHtml(m_doc->toHtml());` you effectively return the old color. That is why the color changes only the first time.

By the way, the widget now changes its color, but has lost its content.

### Solution

It is hard to find an elegant solution, because in this case markup and styles are not kept separate, as in real `HTML` and `CSS`, but the style is embedded by Qt in the markup. The one thing which comes to my mind, is to parse the content of `m_doc` manually.

**Note:** Such a solution would be extremely fragile and I advise strongly against it. Maybe instead of using a stylesheet, change the background color by setting up the palette of the widget, which renders the content of the `QTextDocument` on the screen.

**Note:** In any case this does not seem like the intended behavior, at least it does not match the description in the documentation, so I would have reported it as a bug to Qt, if I were you.

### Example

Here is an example I wrote for you in order to demonstrate the proposed solution:

```
void DocumentHandler::setBackgroundColor(const QColor &color)
{
    const QString &bgcolor("bgcolor=\"");
    QString html(m_doc->toHtml());
    int n = html.indexOf(bgcolor, html.indexOf("<body"));
    int k = n + bgcolor.length();

    m_doc->setDefaultStyleSheet("body { background-color: '" + color.name() + "' }");

    if (n >= 0)
        html.replace(n + bgcolor.length(), html.mid(k, html.indexOf("\"", n + bgcolor.length()) - k).length(), color.name());

    m_doc->setHtml(html);
    m_backgroundColor = color.name(); // QColor variable

    emit backgroundColorChanged();
}
```