# What's the difference between polish()/unpolish() and update()?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtwidgets, qstyle

I did research on all of them. I saw that [docs](https://wiki.qt.io/Dynamic_Properties_and_Stylesheets) use just unpolish() and polish(), but stackoverflows answers use them with update().
I tried and polish() without unpolish() and update() and it works.
So what's the diffrence? Using only polish() is safe?

Comment: What classes do these methods belong to? I found `polish()` and `unpolish` within `QStyle` but that does not have an `update()` method.

Comment: You're right. I'm talking about code like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562716/changing-stylesheet-dynamically
When you call update on widget at the end.